# How to keep some variables fixed and others random during simulation?

Tags: r, simulation, statistics-bootstrap

I am a novice to R and I can’t figure out a solution to my problem.

Imagine that I have created three normally distributed variables, x, y and z (n=100 in each with a mean of 0 and a sd of 1). The variables are independent from each other (r~0). Then I create two new variables x*z and y*z (i.e the interaction between x, z and y, z.).

Now assume that I want to keep x and y fixed and randomly sample from z (or create a new z) before the interactions are computed and, after every new random sample from z, compute the interactions and calculate the correlation coefficient between them (for the sake of argument lets say I want to do this 100 times) and print the 100 correlations to a new datafile for further analysis. How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure that this is what you are asking for. Give it a check.

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rnorm(100)
z<-rnorm(100)
xz<-x*z
yz<-y*z

co<-data.frame(nrow=100, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:100){
  z[i]<-rnorm(1)
  xz[i]<-z[i]*x[i]
  yz[i]<-z[i]*y[i]
 co[i,]<-c(cor(z,x), cor(z,y))
}
```

Comment: It seems exactly like what I wanted (thanks!!!). Now, if I wanted to change say Y instead of Z, I would replace the z[i]<-rnorm(1) with y[i]<-rnorm(1)? And also if I want to look at the correlation xz,yz I change in the cor(z,x) to cor(xz,yz)? 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, it is exactly what you need to do. If my answer responds to all your doubts please accept it clicking on the tick next to it and make it become green. Thank you.

Comment: And say if I want to run more correlations say cor(x,y) cor(x,z) cor(y,z) cor(xz, yz) I change ncol=2 to ncol=4?